# Trouble making CLI (Command Line Interface) work with sublime on MAC OS X

Tags: force.com, commandline

I've downloaded the CLI from http://force-cli.heroku.com/ and have it on my ~/Downloads. After that I change it's permission to 777 and added it to my $PATH.

I installed the "lightning" package on my sublime but when I start sublime I get the following:

```
error: Sublime Lightning Plugin requires the Force.com CLI to functionn

Please visit force-cli.herokuapp.com to installthe Force.com CLI.

If you have already installed it, please make sure that you have stored it or created a symlink to it in Sublime's default path.
```

Trouble begins when I try to login to salesforce using the sublime menu. I keep get as response the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 535, in run_
return self.run()
File "lightningsave in /Users/vinicius/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Lightning.sublime-package", line 323, in run
File "lightningsave in /Users/vinicius/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Lightning.sublime-package", line 161, in get_forcecli_version
File "./subprocess.py", line 824, in __init__
File "./subprocess.py", line 1448, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'force'
```

If I do

```
echo $PATH
```

I get
    /Users/vinicius/Downloads/force:/Users/vinicius/Downloads/:/Users/vinicius/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbindfa

If I type force on my command line anywhere I get a list of force commands as expected by having it on my path.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue with sublime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got the same problem. I'am also using os x with ST3. 
The problem is caused by the fact, that ST3 is not using system PATH and it can't resolve force-cli executable. 
To solve that I installed plugin through Package Control called Fix Mac Path.
There is a link to repo and description https://github.com/int3h/SublimeFixMacPath
Hope it would help you.

Comment: This did it! Tnx!